# Use object values passed into another function with apply_filter

Tags: php, html, wordpress, customization

First of all what I'm trying to do is have an html tag inserted that I can then target with css.

Here's the current html that I have to work with:

```
<p>
  <a href="https://account.danijohnson.com/members/rebecca-deacetis/">Rebecca DeAcetis</a>
    posted an update in the group 
  <a href="https://account.danijohnson.com/bb-groups/creating-a-dynasty-november-2020/">Creating a Dynasty™ November 2020</a>
  <a href="https://account.danijohnson.com/activity/p/6965/" class="view activity-time-since">. 
    <span class="time-since">2 days ago</span>
  </a>
</p>
```

What I would like is to have " posted an update in the group " wrapped with `<span class="activity-action"></span>`

The plugin function that is creating the html is:

```
/**
 * Format groups 'activity_update' activity actions.
 *
 * @since BuddyBoss 1.1.9
 *
 * @param string $action   Static activity action.
 * @param object $activity Activity data object.
 * @return string
 */
function bp_groups_format_activity_action_activity_update( $action, $activity ) {
    $user_link = bp_core_get_userlink( $activity->user_id );

    $group      = groups_get_group( $activity->item_id );
    $group_link = '<a href="' . esc_url( bp_get_group_permalink( $group ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $group->name ) . '</a>';

    $action = sprintf( __( '%1$s posted an update in the group %2$s', 'buddyboss' ), $user_link, $group_link );

    /**
     * Filters the groups 'activity_update' activity actions.
     *
     * @since BuddyBoss 1.1.9
     *
     * @param string $action   The groups 'activity_update' activity actions.
     * @param object $activity Activity data object.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'bp_groups_format_activity_action_activity_update', $action, $activity );
}
```

I've tried adding this to my theme functions.php:

```
function add_span_to_timeline_action($action) {
  
  $action = sprintf( '%1$s<span class="activtiy-action"> posted in the group %2$s</span>', $user_link, $group_link );
  return $action;
}
add_filter('bp_groups_format_activity_action_activity_update','add_span_to_timeline_action');
```

It does update the html and add the `<span>` tags but the `<a>` elements don't work because the $user_link and $group_link variables are not defined in my function.

I can't figure out how to make the $activity object available inside my function to that I can define the link variables.

I know accomplish the css I want with javascript/jquery but I'd like not rely on that because the activity loads on the page and updates with ajax so I'd have to have a setTimeout setInterval so that the activity has loaded which would result in the page updating after it's already loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original filter passes the `$activity` variable, so you have access to it too:

```php
function add_span_to_timeline_action($action, $activity) {

    $user_link = bp_core_get_userlink( $activity->user_id );

    $group      = groups_get_group( $activity->item_id );
    $group_link = '<a href="' . esc_url( bp_get_group_permalink( $group ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $group->name ) . '</a>';

    $action = sprintf( '%1$s<span class="activity-action"> posted in the group %2$s</span>', $user_link, $group_link );
    return $action;
}
add_filter('bp_groups_format_activity_action_activity_update','add_span_to_timeline_action', 10, 2);
```

Just make sure you update the parameter count on the `add_filter` (10 - priority, 2 - argument count)

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but I didn't have the priority and argument count set. That worked.

Comment: Yeah, that's usually what most people forget. Most of the time, WP will throw an error if you have `define('WP_DEBUG', TRUE)` in your wp-config.php file.

Comment: Also, priority can be whatever, but 10 is *generally* the default.